How to create randomized order in listview widget
Has anyone figured out how to randomize the contents of a listview widget. i shuffled it but the list keeps shuffling when i interact with it.
I've tried creating a custom function that shuffles the list content(for context: the data I'm trying to shuffle is of data type). The shuffle is successful, but when testing, the order keeps shuffling when i interacted with the list. i realized its because some actions have "rebuild current page". However, if i switch to "no rebuild page" the whole page doesn't work as in tended. does anyone have an alternative?

image above shows how the specific data i want to shuffle

image above shows the question data scheme

image above shows the data scheme for options

image above shows the custom function

the image shows how i implemented the custom function

the image shows the action with "rebuild current page"

image shows output after clicking on the list

image shows the output after clicking on the list again in the same page

Just wondering if you called your custom function at the right moment? like it needs to be just before generating the page then I would do another page to highlight the correct answer and pass the reference. To avoid that when you reload to compare the answer that it would reload the page. Maybe a better way to get it done though

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
